# Rails 4 save strong parameters array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to do a post request to save JSON in my database.  Here's how the JSON data looks like in my rails console:

```
Parameters: {
"name"=>"Keyboard tutorial", "description"=>"keyboard description", "category"=>"Keyboards", "picture"=>"keyboards.jpg",
"lessons_attributes"=>[
{"name"=>"lesson 1", "category"=>"Content", "body"=>"lesson body"},{"name"=>"lesson 2", "category"=>"Video", "body"=>"link"}
],
"tutorial"=>{"name"=>"Keyboard tutorial", "description"=>"keyboard description", "category"=>"Keyboards", "picture"=>"keyboards.jpg"}
}
```

So I'm trying to save each item in the lessons_attributes array into the Lesson database.

Here's my create action. It's saving the other stuff, just not the lesson_attributes...

```
    def create
        @tutorial = Tutorial.new(tutorials_params)

        if @tutorial.save
            params.permit(lessons_attributes: [:name, :category, :body]).each do |lesson_params|
                @tutorial.lessons << Lesson.create(lesson_params)
            end                
            redirect_to tutorials_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
```

Models

```
        class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
            belongs_to :tutorial
        end
        class Tutorial < ActiveRecord::Base
            has_many :lessons
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
def create
  @tutorial = Tutorial.new(tutorials_params)

  if @tutorial.save
     params["lessons_attributes"].each do |lesson_attribute|
       @tutorial.lessons.create(lesson_params)
     end                
     redirect_to tutorials_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```